Metallic Puzzle

I've had this metallic puzzle for a very long time (actually it's a replica since the original was lost). It was bought in a shop were I was told long ago that it must have a solution.
The question is, topologically speaking, does it have solution?
Just need to know whether it has a solution to avoid wasting more time!

It is the Figure 8 Puzzle by Stewart Coffin.
This puzzle is

 impossible to solve, assuming the eyelets at the ends of the wire are properly closed loops.
 See also this video, where a reasonable argument is given for its impossibility, based on an idea from a mathematical paper by Paul Melvin where the puzzle is proved impossible.


Finally!! I can leave it then to rest and stop wasting my time! Or perhaps I can lend it to my brother in law... :D
Many thanks for your help!
